# Describing pain, a very painful situation

Tags: translation, words

I have the following sentence to translate for class.

> 頭と歯と指と耳と足が痛くて、
>       苦しくて、
>       気持ちが悪かったので、
>       九時半すぎに
>       薬局に行かせた。

So far I have the following.

> My head and teeth and fingers and ears and legs/feet hurt and
>       it was painful and
>       my feeling was bad so
>       a bit after 9:30
>       I made him go to the pharmacy.

I am not sure if I am missing something about the nuances of the pain structures.

The 2nd and 3rd rows seem a bit redundant to the 1st row. Is there some special meaning I am missing? **Since the 1st row has already expressed pain, how is the 2nd and 3rd row's meaning different or how does it add to the description of pain?**

Also, is the すぎ correctly translated as "a bit after"?

Comment: You translated 気持ちが悪かった too literally. It does not mean what you said.

Comment: Maybe "I felt bad"? It all just seems so redundant.

Comment: I think you mean to ask "is the すぎ correctly translated as "a bit after", not "before": すぎ comes from the verb 過ぎる which means exceed or pass. In this case it just means after but you could infer "a bit". It depends on the context.

Comment: The 気持ちが悪かった means 吐き気がした.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

苦しい has more of a connotation of suffering, or going through hardship.

Because the speaker is suffering from hurting in all these places, 気持ちが悪くなった。